# Auto-change the physics of an object after a change of his size

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am new to Corona and Lua. I have the following question:

I have an object `cake` with these physics parameters (doesn't really matters):

```
["cake1"] = {




                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   -21, 62.5  ,  -36, 62.5  ,  -50, 55.5  ,  -58.5, 46  ,  -36, -38.5  ,  57, -40.5  ,  57.5, 34  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   -7.5, -63  ,  -13, -61.5  ,  -12, -64.5  ,  -8, -64.5  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   -12, -64.5  ,  -13, -61.5  ,  -17.5, -56  ,  -21, -52.5  ,  -18.5, -60  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   -47, -37.5  ,  -58.5, 46  ,  -58.5, -33  ,  -53, -37.5  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   -26, -52.5  ,  -21, -52.5  ,  -18.5, -52  ,  -9, -47.5  ,  -6.5, -41  ,  -36, -38.5  ,  -34.5, -46  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   -36, -38.5  ,  -58.5, 46  ,  -47, -37.5  ,  -42, -39.5  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   -6.5, -41  ,  -9, -47.5  ,  -6.5, -44  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   25, -40.5  ,  7, -40.5  ,  17, -42.5  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   48, -42.5  ,  57, -40.5  ,  25, -40.5  ,  32, -42.5  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   -18.5, -52  ,  -21, -52.5  ,  -17.5, -56  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   7, -40.5  ,  -36, -38.5  ,  -6.5, -41  }
                    }
                     ,
                    {
                    pe_fixture_id = "", density = 2, friction = 0, bounce = 0, 
                    filter = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 65535, groupIndex = 0 },
                    shape = {   25, -40.5  ,  -36, -38.5  ,  7, -40.5  }
                    }



        }
```

and when I insert it to the scene I have the following result:

[image]

The `cake` is too large so I use `cake1:scale(0.5,0.5)` to change his size.The problem is that the physics didn't change automatically to apply to its new size and the result is:

[image]

**Are there any easy way to change the size of an object and the physics automatically fit to the new size or I have to rewrite them?**

Comment: you can put physics on each cake so when you call the size of each cake the physics will automatically change

Comment: @DevfaR if you mean to change size of an object with an editor, let's say `Photoshop` and then apply the physics, that's not efficient. I will have 5-10 `png` files of each object

If you mean to use `object.size` function, I tried it and the size of the object didn't change.

I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding i did't notice the last image it looks like it was floating did you try adding radius to your physics like physics.addBody(object {radius = 0.5} )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using physics editor for the purpose..?

Then there is `scaleFactor` provided. You can assign physics to the object with this scale factor, as below:

```
local scaleFactor = 1.0
local physicsData = (require "shapedefs").physicsData(scaleFactor)
local shape = display.newImage("objectname.png")
physics.addBody( shape, physicsData:get("objectname") )
```

And when you change the scaleFactor, the size of physics area will automatically change.

For more details, visit : http://velluminteractive.com/advanced-physics-bodies-with-physics-editor-and-corona-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

You have changed scale 0.5 smaller, means you have to change all physics objects smaller by 0.5, use calculator to make your normal numbers / 2 and for numbers less than 0 / 2 them and sum your number with result number, here is an example:

24 = 12

-24 = -36